# Search engine for snippets in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I m looking for an extension in visual studio code that can search for snippets by their description or name , kinda like a search engine for snippets extension, all inside visual studio code.

Comment: Look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.snippets-view might be as close as you will get.

Comment: thanx Mark, thats actually very helpful!